# Image rename and value insert into my mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image

What I would like is for an uploaded image to have a random name that would would be inserted into my data base so I can call it on user profiles. I have the php code that will upload files to the local disc but no values are being submitted into the mysql row for the user. Also, all the images are being named image.jpg and overwriting each other. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
<?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images/uploaded/user_images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form  

 $photo=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("server", "root", "pass") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('$photo')") ; 
 //Writes the information to the database
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo ('name')
    VALUES ('$photo')") ;



 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: try to rename the file with random string.

Comment: **A:** Google => `rename uploaded file with random name` and use `mt_rand()` or `uniqid()` with a UNIX timestamp. Plus, have a look on the right under **"Related"** >>>

Comment: *"all the images are being named image.jpg"* --- Obviously coming from an iPhone/iPod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For I start I would like to ask you how do you know which user has which picture? Becouse you just store images in table without any user ID. I suggest that you redesign your database.

Then I will use this for an image name instead of completely random string.

```
$_FILES['photo']['name'] = "image_" . round(microtime(true) * 1000) . ".jpg";
```

Or get the number of images in database and increase it by one. That way you cannot end up with multiple images with same name.

Comment: the users data is saved in the DB, it has the user name email add pass word and all of that and a section for the photo so thats what i am tring to figure out is how to add the name of the photo to the photo section of the database

Comment: You will need user ID for that.

Comment: ok perfect, I added your suggestion above and it works to rename the files, I have the user id section but I do not know how to save the image location to the user id if that makes sense I am very new to this and still trying to learn,

Comment: Lets say that you already have a user in table users with userID 1. Then you will assign profile image to user with `UPDATE users SET photo="image_name" WHERE userID = 1;`. If you don't have an ID in your table you should create it. Every table needs an ID.